# Generating jacoco report in multiple mvn commands

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a project with a lot of tests. In order to reduce the CI time, my unit tests are run in parallel of my integration tests and same for other test types.

Each test job generate it's own jacoco reports in binary and XML format. But i need a way to combine those into one final report I can send to sonar (so binary or XML if I'm correct) AND an XML version for Gitlab coverage widget.

Ideally I could just generate binary report in my tests and then combine and convert those to XML. So I can run `mvn test` instead of `mvn verify`. But I believe it's not possible to convert jacoco binary to XML. Right ?

So I could generate XML in each job with `mvn verify` but then I still have no idea of the proper way to combine those reports. Maybe it's not even possible because of course you can't just add all coverage percentage from the same class. So is there enough info in XML (or even binary) reports to be able to combine them ?